Call CallVoidMethod multiple time cause crash
I'm trying to use JSI and JNI in a React-Native app for sending ArrayBuffer without encoding data.
For this, I have a C++ function receiveDataFromCpp():
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_mymodule_rtnstreamstream_RTNStreamModule_nativeInstall(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jlong jsi) {
    jsi::Runtime * runtime = reinterpret_cast<jsi::Runtime *>(jsi);
    jobject rtnstream_kt_module = env->NewGlobalRef(thiz);
    rtnstream::install(*runtime, env, rtnstream_kt_module);
}

jsi::Function getDeviceName = jsi::Function::createFromHostFunction(
        jsiRuntime,
        jsi::PropNameID::forAscii(jsiRuntime, "receiveDataFromCpp"),
        0,
        [&env, &rtnstream_kt_module](
                jsi::Runtime& runtime,
                const jsi::Value& thisValue,
                const jsi::Value* arguments,
                std::size_t count
        ) -> jsi::Value {
            if (count != 1 || !arguments[0].isObject()) {
                throw jsi::JSError(runtime, "Argument has to be an ArrayBuffer");
            }

            jsi::Object object = arguments[0].asObject(runtime);
            jsi::ArrayBuffer arrayBuffer = object.getArrayBuffer(runtime);

            size_t bufferSize = arrayBuffer.size(runtime);
            uint8_t* bufferData = arrayBuffer.data(runtime);

            jbyteArray jbyteArrayData = env->NewByteArray(bufferSize);
            env->SetByteArrayRegion(jbyteArrayData, 0, bufferSize, reinterpret_cast<const jbyte*>(bufferData));

            jclass java_class = env->FindClass("com/myModule/RTNStreamModule");

            jmethodID receiveDataFromCpp = env->GetMethodID(java_class, "receiveDataFromCpp", "([B)V"); // My kotlin method

            env->CallVoidMethod(rtnstream_kt_module, receiveDataFromCpp, jbyteArrayData);

            if (jbyteArrayData != nullptr) {
                env->DeleteLocalRef(jbyteArrayData); // Clean up
            }

            return jsi::Value(static_cast<double>(bufferSize));
        });

And from JS, just use receiveDataFromCpp(data);
It works the first time, but if I re-run receiveDataFromCpp, I get this crash error:

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 26510 (mqt_v_js), pid 26432

I do not understand because I think the clean up is correct. Can anyone help me?

You need to start putting some breakpoints or print statements and see what's null. Check that bufferSize is valid and correct. Check that bufferData is not null. Check that rtnstream_kt_module is not null.

Also, any JNIEnv *env value can not be safely used outside of the context of getting it from the JVM, whether or not it was passed as an argument from a JNI call or from attaching the current thread to the JVM.  And JNIEnv *env values aren't the only values that can't safely be cached.  This doesn't appear to be a complete example, so if you are caching values like that, you can't.
